# Match the Stack Exchange URLs

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

### Prologue

After installing an anti-XSS browser extension, Stack Snippets suddenly stopped working all across the Stack Exchange network. I could no longer learn from [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com), see working demos on [User Experience](//ux.stackexchange.com) and, worst of all, could not test JavaScript answers on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com)! Desperately I searched for a remedy, and found a small input box in the settings, in which could place a single regex. I couldn't fit all of the Stack Exchange sites in this one, small box, so I asked for help. This is that question.

### Task

Your task is to create a regular expression that matches all of the Stack Exchange website URLs, without matching any domains not owned by Stack Overflow Inc..

Your regular expression must match all URLs with the following parts:

- `protocol`: this will either be `http://` or `https://`.
- `domain`: this will be an item from this list:

  ```
  stackoverflow.com
  www.stackoverflow.com
  facebook.stackoverflow.com
  serverfault.com
  superuser.com
  meta.stackexchange.com
  webapps.stackexchange.com
  nothingtoinstall.com
  meta.webapps.stackexchange.com
  meta.nothingtoinstall.com
  gaming.stackexchange.com
  arqade.com
  thearqade.com
  meta.gaming.stackexchange.com
  meta.arqade.com
  meta.thearqade.com
  webmasters.stackexchange.com
  webmaster.stackexchange.com
  meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com
  meta.webmaster.stackexchange.com
  cooking.stackexchange.com
  seasonedadvice.com
  meta.cooking.stackexchange.com
  meta.seasonedadvice.com
  gamedev.stackexchange.com
  meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com
  photo.stackexchange.com
  photography.stackexchange.com
  photos.stackexchange.com
  meta.photo.stackexchange.com
  meta.photography.stackexchange.com
  meta.photos.stackexchange.com
  stats.stackexchange.com
  statistics.stackexchange.com
  crossvalidated.com
  meta.stats.stackexchange.com
  meta.statistics.stackexchange.com
  math.stackexchange.com
  maths.stackexchange.com
  mathematics.stackexchange.com
  meta.math.stackexchange.com
  diy.stackexchange.com
  meta.diy.stackexchange.com
  meta.superuser.com
  meta.serverfault.com
  gis.stackexchange.com
  meta.gis.stackexchange.com
  tex.stackexchange.com
  meta.tex.stackexchange.com
  askubuntu.com
  ubuntu.stackexchange.com
  meta.askubuntu.com
  meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com
  money.stackexchange.com
  basicallymoney.com
  www.basicallymoney.com
  meta.money.stackexchange.com
  english.stackexchange.com
  elu.stackexchange.com
  meta.english.stackexchange.com
  stackapps.com
  ux.stackexchange.com
  ui.stackexchange.com
  meta.ux.stackexchange.com
  meta.ui.stackexchange.com
  unix.stackexchange.com
  linux.stackexchange.com
  meta.unix.stackexchange.com
  meta.linux.stackexchange.com
  wordpress.stackexchange.com
  meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com
  cstheory.stackexchange.com
  meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com
  apple.stackexchange.com
  askdifferent.com
  meta.apple.stackexchange.com
  rpg.stackexchange.com
  meta.rpg.stackexchange.com
  bicycles.stackexchange.com
  bicycle.stackexchange.com
  cycling.stackexchange.com
  bikes.stackexchange.com
  meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com
  meta.bicycle.stackexchange.com
  programmers.stackexchange.com
  programmer.stackexchange.com
  meta.programmers.stackexchange.com
  electronics.stackexchange.com
  chiphacker.com
  www.chiphacker.com
  meta.electronics.stackexchange.com
  android.stackexchange.com
  meta.android.stackexchange.com
  boardgames.stackexchange.com
  boardgame.stackexchange.com
  meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com
  physics.stackexchange.com
  meta.physics.stackexchange.com
  homebrew.stackexchange.com
  homebrewing.stackexchange.com
  brewadvice.com
  meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com
  meta.homebrewing.stackexchange.com
  security.stackexchange.com
  itsecurity.stackexchange.com
  meta.security.stackexchange.com
  meta.itsecurity.stackexchange.com
  writers.stackexchange.com
  writer.stackexchange.com
  writing.stackexchange.com
  meta.writers.stackexchange.com
  video.stackexchange.com
  avp.stackexchange.com
  meta.video.stackexchange.com
  meta.avp.stackexchange.com
  graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
  graphicsdesign.stackexchange.com
  graphicdesigns.stackexchange.com
  meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
  dba.stackexchange.com
  meta.dba.stackexchange.com
  scifi.stackexchange.com
  sciencefiction.stackexchange.com
  fantasy.stackexchange.com
  meta.scifi.stackexchange.com
  codereview.stackexchange.com
  meta.codereview.stackexchange.com
  codegolf.stackexchange.com
  meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com
  quant.stackexchange.com
  meta.quant.stackexchange.com
  pm.stackexchange.com
  meta.pm.stackexchange.com
  skeptics.stackexchange.com
  skeptic.stackexchange.com
  skepticexchange.com
  meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com
  fitness.stackexchange.com
  meta.fitness.stackexchange.com
  drupal.stackexchange.com
  meta.drupal.stackexchange.com
  mechanics.stackexchange.com
  garage.stackexchange.com
  meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com
  meta.garage.stackexchange.com
  parenting.stackexchange.com
  meta.parenting.stackexchange.com
  sharepoint.stackexchange.com
  sharepointoverflow.com
  www.sharepointoverflow.com
  meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com
  music.stackexchange.com
  guitars.stackexchange.com
  guitar.stackexchange.com
  meta.music.stackexchange.com
  sqa.stackexchange.com
  meta.sqa.stackexchange.com
  judaism.stackexchange.com
  mi.yodeya.com
  yodeya.com
  yodeya.stackexchange.com
  miyodeya.com
  meta.judaism.stackexchange.com
  german.stackexchange.com
  deutsch.stackexchange.com
  meta.german.stackexchange.com
  japanese.stackexchange.com
  meta.japanese.stackexchange.com
  philosophy.stackexchange.com
  meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com
  gardening.stackexchange.com
  landscaping.stackexchange.com
  meta.gardening.stackexchange.com
  travel.stackexchange.com
  meta.travel.stackexchange.com
  productivity.stackexchange.com
  meta.productivity.stackexchange.com
  crypto.stackexchange.com
  cryptography.stackexchange.com
  meta.crypto.stackexchange.com
  meta.cryptography.stackexchange.com
  dsp.stackexchange.com
  signals.stackexchange.com
  meta.dsp.stackexchange.com
  french.stackexchange.com
  meta.french.stackexchange.com
  christianity.stackexchange.com
  meta.christianity.stackexchange.com
  bitcoin.stackexchange.com
  meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com
  linguistics.stackexchange.com
  linguist.stackexchange.com
  meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com
  hermeneutics.stackexchange.com
  meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com
  history.stackexchange.com
  meta.history.stackexchange.com
  bricks.stackexchange.com
  meta.bricks.stackexchange.com
  spanish.stackexchange.com
  espanol.stackexchange.com
  meta.spanish.stackexchange.com
  scicomp.stackexchange.com
  meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com
  movies.stackexchange.com
  meta.movies.stackexchange.com
  chinese.stackexchange.com
  meta.chinese.stackexchange.com
  biology.stackexchange.com
  meta.biology.stackexchange.com
  poker.stackexchange.com
  meta.poker.stackexchange.com
  mathematica.stackexchange.com
  meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com
  cogsci.stackexchange.com
  meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com
  outdoors.stackexchange.com
  meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com
  martialarts.stackexchange.com
  meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com
  sports.stackexchange.com
  meta.sports.stackexchange.com
  academia.stackexchange.com
  academics.stackexchange.com
  meta.academia.stackexchange.com
  cs.stackexchange.com
  computerscience.stackexchange.com
  meta.cs.stackexchange.com
  workplace.stackexchange.com
  meta.workplace.stackexchange.com
  windowsphone.stackexchange.com
  meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com
  chemistry.stackexchange.com
  meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com
  chess.stackexchange.com
  meta.chess.stackexchange.com
  raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
  meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
  russian.stackexchange.com
  meta.russian.stackexchange.com
  islam.stackexchange.com
  meta.islam.stackexchange.com
  salesforce.stackexchange.com
  meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com
  patents.stackexchange.com
  askpatents.com
  askpatents.stackexchange.com
  meta.patents.stackexchange.com
  meta.askpatents.com
  meta.askpatents.stackexchange.com
  genealogy.stackexchange.com
  meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com
  robotics.stackexchange.com
  meta.robotics.stackexchange.com
  expressionengine.stackexchange.com
  meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com
  politics.stackexchange.com
  meta.politics.stackexchange.com
  anime.stackexchange.com
  meta.anime.stackexchange.com
  magento.stackexchange.com
  meta.magento.stackexchange.com
  ell.stackexchange.com
  meta.ell.stackexchange.com
  sustainability.stackexchange.com
  meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com
  tridion.stackexchange.com
  meta.tridion.stackexchange.com
  reverseengineering.stackexchange.com
  meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com
  networkengineering.stackexchange.com
  meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com
  opendata.stackexchange.com
  meta.opendata.stackexchange.com
  freelancing.stackexchange.com
  meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com
  blender.stackexchange.com
  meta.blender.stackexchange.com
  mathoverflow.net
  mathoverflow.stackexchange.com
  mathoverflow.com
  meta.mathoverflow.net
  space.stackexchange.com
  thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com
  meta.space.stackexchange.com
  sound.stackexchange.com
  socialsounddesign.com
  sounddesign.stackexchange.com
  meta.sound.stackexchange.com
  astronomy.stackexchange.com
  meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com
  tor.stackexchange.com
  meta.tor.stackexchange.com
  pets.stackexchange.com
  meta.pets.stackexchange.com
  ham.stackexchange.com
  meta.ham.stackexchange.com
  italian.stackexchange.com
  meta.italian.stackexchange.com
  pt.stackoverflow.com
  br.stackoverflow.com
  stackoverflow.com.br
  meta.pt.stackoverflow.com
  meta.br.stackoverflow.com
  aviation.stackexchange.com
  meta.aviation.stackexchange.com
  ebooks.stackexchange.com
  meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com
  alcohol.stackexchange.com
  beer.stackexchange.com
  dranks.stackexchange.com
  meta.alcohol.stackexchange.com
  meta.beer.stackexchange.com
  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  arduino.stackexchange.com
  meta.arduino.stackexchange.com
  cs50.stackexchange.com
  meta.cs50.stackexchange.com
  expatriates.stackexchange.com
  expats.stackexchange.com
  meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com
  matheducators.stackexchange.com
  meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com
  meta.stackoverflow.com
  earthscience.stackexchange.com
  meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com
  joomla.stackexchange.com
  meta.joomla.stackexchange.com
  datascience.stackexchange.com
  meta.datascience.stackexchange.com
  puzzling.stackexchange.com
  meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com
  craftcms.stackexchange.com
  meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com
  buddhism.stackexchange.com
  meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com
  hinduism.stackexchange.com
  meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com
  communitybuilding.stackexchange.com
  moderator.stackexchange.com
  moderators.stackexchange.com
  meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com
  meta.moderators.stackexchange.com
  startups.stackexchange.com
  meta.startups.stackexchange.com
  worldbuilding.stackexchange.com
  meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com
  ja.stackoverflow.com
  jp.stackoverflow.com
  meta.ja.stackoverflow.com
  emacs.stackexchange.com
  meta.emacs.stackexchange.com
  hsm.stackexchange.com
  meta.hsm.stackexchange.com
  economics.stackexchange.com
  meta.economics.stackexchange.com
  lifehacks.stackexchange.com
  meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com
  engineering.stackexchange.com
  meta.engineering.stackexchange.com
  coffee.stackexchange.com
  meta.coffee.stackexchange.com
  vi.stackexchange.com
  vim.stackexchange.com
  meta.vi.stackexchange.com
  musicfans.stackexchange.com
  meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com
  woodworking.stackexchange.com
  meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com
  civicrm.stackexchange.com
  meta.civicrm.stackexchange.com
  health.stackexchange.com
  meta.health.stackexchange.com
  ru.stackoverflow.com
  hashcode.ru
  stackoverflow.ru
  meta.ru.stackoverflow.com
  meta.hashcode.ru
  rus.stackexchange.com
  russ.hashcode.ru
  russ.stackexchange.com
  meta.rus.stackexchange.com
  mythology.stackexchange.com
  meta.mythology.stackexchange.com
  law.stackexchange.com
  meta.law.stackexchange.com
  opensource.stackexchange.com
  meta.opensource.stackexchange.com
  elementaryos.stackexchange.com
  meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com
  portuguese.stackexchange.com
  meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com
  computergraphics.stackexchange.com
  meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com
  hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  es.stackoverflow.com
  meta.es.stackoverflow.com
  3dprinting.stackexchange.com
  threedprinting.stackexchange.com
  meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com
  ethereum.stackexchange.com
  meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com
  latin.stackexchange.com
  meta.latin.stackexchange.com
  languagelearning.stackexchange.com
  meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com
  retrocomputing.stackexchange.com
  meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com
  crafts.stackexchange.com
  meta.crafts.stackexchange.com
  korean.stackexchange.com
  meta.korean.stackexchange.com
  monero.stackexchange.com
  meta.monero.stackexchange.com
  ai.stackexchange.com
  meta.ai.stackexchange.com
  esperanto.stackexchange.com
  meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com
  sitecore.stackexchange.com
  meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com
  ```
- `page`: this will either be the empty string, `/` or `/` followed by any string

The url will be the string created by appending `protocol`, `domain` and `page` to each other, in that order.

### Testcases

Your regex must match:

```
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com
https://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234
http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/thisisa404.php?file=command.com
```

Your regex must not match:

```
http//codegolf.stackexchange.com/
https://meta.stackoverflow.com.fakesite.dodgy/cgi-bin/virus.cgi?vector=apt
file://www.stackoverflow.com/
http://ripoff.com/stackoverflow.com/q/1234/
```

Your regex may match:

```
http://panda.stackexchange.com/
https://www.meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com
http://alpha.beta.charlie.delta.chiphacker.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites/
```

because these are owned by Stack Exchange Inc. and so will not be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest regular expression wins!

Comment: What do you mean 'may match'? Shouldn't those also be in 'must match'? We generally do not take kindly to 'bonus objectives' here, as in a code golf context they'll virtually always be skipped to save bytes.

Comment: @orlp I see this as more like ASCII-art challenges that say, "Your program may output any amount of trailing whitespace as long as the output looks like the example." In other words, these are some cases that the programmer doesn't have to worry about explicitly disallowing. If they fail, fine; if they match, fine.

Comment: @orlp I added them because, for most implementation techniques, they *save* bytes.

Answer (score 16):

## <strike>337</strike> <strike>336</strike> <strike>333</strike> 327 bytes

```
^https?://([^/]+\.)*(stackoverflow\.(com(\.br)?|ru)|mathoverflow\.(com|net)|hashcode\.ru|((the)?arqade|chiphacker|(mi)?yodeya|ask(ubuntu|different|patents)|(seasoned|brew)advice|s(erverfault|(tack|keptic)exchange|uperuser|tackapps|harepointoverflow|ocialsounddesign)|nothingtoinstall|crossvalidated|basicallymoney)\.com)(/.*)?$
```

Doesn't use any fancy regex features, so it should work in any regex flavour.

Comment: @TimmyD When I tried it, it matched one of the optional ones too... [regexr](//regexr.com/3eaom)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I forgot stackexchange and start/end markers.

Comment: @oflp It doesn't match *anything* now... Maybe start/end markers don't work in regexr? [regexr](//regexr.com/3eaom)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No clue, I never use regexr. Try inputting one string at a time rather than a full text.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You need to enable the multi line flag (upper right corner) else it matches start/end of the entire text, rather than start/end of the line.

Comment: You can can save a few bytes by combining `seasonedadvice` with `brewadvice` instead of with the other `s` words.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but I realised it was essentially identical to yours except for using `(\w+\.)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

### <s>359</s> 348 bytes

```
https?:\/\/(([^/]+\.)*((stack(overflow|apps|exchange)|ask(ubuntu|different|patents)|(the)?arqade|serverfault|superuser|nothingtoinstall|(seasoned|brew)advice|crossvalidated|basicallymoney|chiphacker|skepticexchange|(sharepoint|math)overflow|(mi)?yodea|socialsounddesign)\.com)|(stackoverflow(\.com\.br|\.ru)|hashcode\.ru|mathoverflow\.net))(\/.*)?$
```

[Test it out](http://regexr.com/3eaod) on regexr

Comment: This came super handy for my personal CSS to apply on all SE sites :)

Answer (score 3):

## <strike>2179 2092</strike> 1966 bytes

```
https?:\/\/((((www|facebook|jp|(meta\.?)?(es|ru|ja|pt|br)?)\.)?stackoverflow\.com)|(stackoverflow\.(ru|com\.br))|(((russ|meta)\.)?hashcode\.ru)|(crossvalidated|socialsounddesign|mathoverflow|(mi\.?)?yodeya|(www\.)?(sharepointoverflow|basicallymoney)|skepticexchange|brewadvice|(www\.)?chiphacker|ask(different|ubuntu)|stackapps|(meta\.)?(nothingtoinstall|arqade|thearqade|seasonedadvice|superuser|serverfault|ask(ubuntu|patents)))\.com|((meta\.)?mathoverflow\.net)|(((meta\.)?((3|three)dprinting|(ask)?patents|(community|world)building|(econo|acade)mics|(it)?security|(reverse|network)?engineering|a(cademia|i|lcohol|ndroid|nime|pple|rduino|stronomy|viation|vp)|b((e|lend)er|i(cycles?|kes|ology|tcoin)|oardgames?|ricks|uddhism)|c(h(emistry|ess|inese|ristianity)|ivicrm|o(de(review|golf)|ffee|gsci|mputer(science|graphics)|oking)|r(aftcms|afts|ypto(graphy)?)|s(50)?|stheory)|d(ba|eutsch|iy|ranks|rupal|sp)|(earth|data)science|e(books|l(ectronics|ementaryos|l|u)|macs|nglish|spanol|speranto|thereum|xp(at(s|riates)|ressionengine))|f(antasy|itness|re(elancing|nch))|g(a(medev|ming|rage|rdening)|erman|enealogy|is|raphics?designs?|uitars?)|h(am|ealth|ermeneutics|induism|istory|omebrew(ing)?|sm)|(hard|soft)warerecs|islam|italian|j(apanese|oomla|udaism)|korean|l(a((ndscap|nguagelearn)ing|tin|w)|i(fehacks|nguist(ics)?|nux|))|m(a(gento|rtialarts|th(educators|ematica|ematics|s|overflow)?)|eta|echanics|o(derators?|nero|ney|vies)|usic(fans)?|ythology)|o(pen(data|source)|utdoors)|(cycl|parent|retrocomput)ing|p(ets|h(ilosophy|oto(graphy|s)?|ysics)|m|o(ker|litics|rtuguese)|roductivity|rogrammers?|uzzling)|quant|r(aspberrypi|obotics|pg|us(s|sian)?)|s(alesforce|ci(comp|encefiction|fi)|harepoint|ignals|itecore|keptics?|ound(design)?|p(ace|anish|orts)|qa|tartups|tat(s|istics)|ustainability)|t(ex|hefinalfrontier|or|ravel|ridion)|u(buntu|i|nix|x)|vi(deo|m)?|w(eb(apps|masters?)|indowsphone|o(odworking|rdpress|rkplace)|rit(ers?|ing))|(yodeya)))\.stackexchange\.com))(\/|$)
```

Matches exactly the domains listed and nothing else. I did most of the compressing by hand. I'm a bit embarrassed that I spent this much time on it.

Comment: Is there any more `.com` compressing you can do?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm sure I could compress a lot more. I might come back to this later.

Comment: All subdomains are considered safe, so you don't need to list any of them.

Comment: @curiousdannii I know, but I wanted to see how small I could make it and only match the given subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

## <s>142</s> <s>140</s> 334 bytes

```
#^https?:\/\/([^\/]*\.)?(hashcode\.ru|mathoverflow\.(com|net)|stackoverflow\.(ru|com(\.br)?)|((stack|skeptic)exchange|stackapps|ask(different|patents|ubuntu)|(brew|seasoned)advice|(the)?arqade|basicallymoney|chiphacker|crossvalidated|nothingtoinstall|serverfault|sharepointoverflow|socialsounddesign|superuser|(mi)?yodeya)\.com)(/|$)#
```

- matches everything on the specified second level domains, path or no path
- uses `#` as delimiter so `/` needs no escaping (saved two bytes)
- compressed manually