# Output all SE sites URLs

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Your challenge is to output this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://serverfault.com/
https://superuser.com/
https://meta.stackexchange.com/
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
https://photo.stackexchange.com/
https://stats.stackexchange.com/
https://math.stackexchange.com/
https://diy.stackexchange.com/
https://gis.stackexchange.com/
https://tex.stackexchange.com/
https://askubuntu.com/
https://money.stackexchange.com/
https://english.stackexchange.com/
https://stackapps.com/
https://ux.stackexchange.com/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
https://android.stackexchange.com/
https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/
https://physics.stackexchange.com/
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/
https://security.stackexchange.com/
https://writers.stackexchange.com/
https://video.stackexchange.com/
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/
https://dba.stackexchange.com/
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
https://quant.stackexchange.com/
https://pm.stackexchange.com/
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/
https://fitness.stackexchange.com/
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/
https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/
https://parenting.stackexchange.com/
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/
https://music.stackexchange.com/
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/
https://german.stackexchange.com/
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/
https://travel.stackexchange.com/
https://productivity.stackexchange.com/
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/
https://french.stackexchange.com/
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/
https://history.stackexchange.com/
https://bricks.stackexchange.com/
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
https://movies.stackexchange.com/
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/
https://biology.stackexchange.com/
https://poker.stackexchange.com/
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/
https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/
https://sports.stackexchange.com/
https://academia.stackexchange.com/
https://cs.stackexchange.com/
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/
https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/
https://chess.stackexchange.com/
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/
https://russian.stackexchange.com/
https://islam.stackexchange.com/
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/
https://patents.stackexchange.com/
https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/
https://politics.stackexchange.com/
https://anime.stackexchange.com/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/
https://ell.stackexchange.com/
https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/
https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/
https://blender.stackexchange.com/
https://mathoverflow.net/
https://space.stackexchange.com/
https://sound.stackexchange.com/
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/
https://tor.stackexchange.com/
https://pets.stackexchange.com/
https://ham.stackexchange.com/
https://italian.stackexchange.com/
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/
https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/
https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/
https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/
https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/
https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/
https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/
https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/
https://startups.stackexchange.com/
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/
https://hsm.stackexchange.com/
https://economics.stackexchange.com/
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/
https://engineering.stackexchange.com/
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/
https://vi.stackexchange.com/
https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/
https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/
https://health.stackexchange.com/
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
https://rus.stackexchange.com/
https://mythology.stackexchange.com/
https://law.stackexchange.com/
https://opensource.stackexchange.com/
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/
https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/
https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/
https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
https://es.stackoverflow.com/
https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/
https://latin.stackexchange.com/
https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/
https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/
https://crafts.stackexchange.com/
https://korean.stackexchange.com/
https://monero.stackexchange.com/
https://ai.stackexchange.com/
https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/
https://iot.stackexchange.com/
https://literature.stackexchange.com/
https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/
https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/
https://devops.stackexchange.com/
```

(trailing whitespace permitted)

Note: these are the only URLs not on StackExchange.com:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://serverfault.com/
https://superuser.com/
https://askubuntu.com/
https://stackapps.com/
https://mathoverflow.net/
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
https://es.stackoverflow.com/
```

All site URLs match this regex:

```
^http?://([^/]+\.)*(stackoverflow\.(com(\.br)?|ru)|mathoverflow\.(com|net)|hashcode\.ru|((the)?arqade|chiphacker|(mi)?yodeya|ask(ubuntu|different|patents)|(seasoned|brew)advice|s(erverfault|(tack|keptic)exchange|uperuser|tackapps|harepointoverflow|ocialsounddesign)|nothingtoinstall|crossvalidated|basicallymoney)\.com)(/.*)?$
```

(based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94736/58826))

You may use any delimiter, not just newlines. Also, order is not important.

### Area 51 is not included.

This is not a dupe of [The Stack Exchange Site List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58502/the-stack-exchange-site-list) or [Recognise Stack Exchange Sites by Their Icon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/recognise-stack-exchange-sites-by-their-icon), because the names involved in the first one are (different `"dba" !== "Database Administrators"`), and you have to deal with separate domains.

Comment: How important is order in the output?

Comment: @ValueInk you can output in any order.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94731/match-the-stack-exchange-urls)

Comment: @programmer5000 what I said on your other challenge also applies to this one, also for the [dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58502/the-stack-exchange-site-list) and the [dupe's dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/recognise-stack-exchange-sites-by-their-icon) -> plain compression is the best algorithm, because the text don't have enough room for any other kind of optimization

Comment: The new domains and abbreviations still don't separate it enough. The other challenge answers use a simple dictionary lookup, it's trivial to modify that to add different domains.